# Symfony 3 JMS payment Paypal Error

Tags: php, symfony, paypal

I come to you because i really don't know what is wrong using this bundle for paypal checkout.

http://jmspaymentcorebundle.readthedocs.io/en/stable/setup.html

This is the link about the bundle and documentation.

My problem is on the end of tutoriel, i have an error that i don't know how to solve.

> CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception
>   JMS\Payment\CoreBundle\Plugin\Exception\ActionRequiredException: "User
>   must authorize the transaction." at
>   C:\wamp64\www\Wolk\vendor\jms\payment-paypal-bundle\JMS\Payment\PaypalBundle\Plugin\ExpressCheckoutPlugin.php
>   line 303

And this is my controller code:

```
<?php
namespace Wolk\PlatformBundle\Controller;

use Wolk\PlatformBundle\Entity\Order;
use JMS\Payment\CoreBundle\Form\ChoosePaymentMethodType;
use JMS\Payment\CoreBundle\PluginController\Result;
use JMS\Payment\CoreBundle\Plugin\AbstractPlugin;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/**
 * @Route("/orders")
 */
class OrdersController extends Controller
{
    /**
 * @Route("/new/{amount}")
 */
public function newAction($amount, $game)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $order = new Order($amount);
    $em->persist($order);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('app_orders_show', [
        'id' => $order->getId(),
        'game' => $game,
    ]));
}

/**
 * @Route("/{id}/show")
 * @Template
 */
public function showAction(Request $request, Order $order, $game)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(ChoosePaymentMethodType::class, null, [
        'amount'   => $order->getAmount(),
        'currency' => 'EUR',
    ]);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $ppc = $this->get('payment.plugin_controller');
        $ppc->createPaymentInstruction($instruction = $form->getData());

        $order->setPaymentInstruction($instruction);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($order);
        $em->flush($order);

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('app_orders_paymentcreate', [
            'id' => $order->getId(),
            'game' => $game,
        ]));
    }

    return [
        'order' => $order,
        'form'  => $form->createView(),
        'game' => $game,
    ];
}

private function createPayment($order)
{
    $instruction = $order->getPaymentInstruction();
    $pendingTransaction = $instruction->getPendingTransaction();

    if ($pendingTransaction !== null) {
        return $pendingTransaction->getPayment();
    }

    $ppc = $this->get('payment.plugin_controller');
    $amount = $instruction->getAmount() - $instruction->getDepositedAmount();

    return $ppc->createPayment($instruction->getId(), $amount);
}

/**
 * @Route("/{id}/payment/create")
 */
public function paymentCreateAction(Order $order)
{
    $payment = $this->createPayment($order);

    $ppc = $this->get('payment.plugin_controller');
    $result = $ppc->approveAndDeposit($payment->getId(), $payment->getTargetAmount());



if ($result->getStatus() === Result::STATUS_PENDING) {
    $ex = $result->getPluginException();

    if ($ex instanceof ActionRequiredException) {
        $action = $ex->getAction();

        if ($action instanceof VisitUrl) {
            return $this->redirect($action->getUrl());
        }
    }
}

throw $result->getPluginException();

    // In a real-world application you wouldn't throw the exception. You would,
    // for example, redirect to the showAction with a flash message informing
    // the user that the payment was not successful.
}

/**
 * @Route("/{id}/payment/complete")
 */
public function paymentCompleteAction(Order $order)
{
    return new Response('Payment complete');
}


}
```

My config.yml (this is only params with sandbox account)

```
jms_payment_paypal:
    username: <USERNAME> # not your account username
    password: <PASSWORD> # not your account password
    signature: <SIGNATURE>
    debug: true
    return_url: https://yourdomain.com
    cancel_url: https://yourdomain.com
```

my routing file

```
app_orders_new:
    path:     /orders/new/{amount}
    defaults: { _controller: "PlatformBundle:Orders:new" }


app_orders_show:
    path:     /orders/{id}/show
    defaults: { _controller: "PlatformBundle:Orders:show" }

app_orders_paymentcreate:
    path:     /orders/{id}/payment/create
    defaults: { _controller: "PlatformBundle:Orders:paymentCreate" }

app_orders_paymentcomplete:
    path:     /orders/{id}/payment/complete
    defaults: { _controller: "PlatformBundle:Orders:paymentComplete" }
```

and the last file, the entity orders:

```
<?php

namespace Wolk\PlatformBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JMS\Payment\CoreBundle\Entity\PaymentInstruction;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="orders")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Order
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /** @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="JMS\Payment\CoreBundle\Entity\PaymentInstruction") */
    private $paymentInstruction;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=10, scale=5) */
    private $amount;

    public function __construct($amount)
    {
        $this->amount = $amount;
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getAmount()
    {
        return $this->amount;
    }

    public function getPaymentInstruction()
    {
        return $this->paymentInstruction;
    }

    public function setPaymentInstruction(PaymentInstruction $instruction)
    {
        $this->paymentInstruction = $instruction;
    }
}
```

I try to search on google everything but i don't find anything x/

Thanks you for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error,I spent a lot f time searching for solution. It turns out that I forgot to add these lines :

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use JMS\Payment\CoreBundle\Plugin\Exception\Action\VisitUrl;
use JMS\Payment\CoreBundle\Plugin\Exception\ActionRequiredException;
```

I post this here,maybe it can help other people.